# Getting values of my childRepeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have 2 repeaters where the first one list the questions and the second one list multiple choice for that specific question. 
However, there are some multiple choice(input type="radio") or Text(input type="text") anwers. Im trying to get the value of either one(radio) or the other(text).

**<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Descricao")%>**

```
                                            <%--    Listagem de Respostas --%>

                                            <asp:Repeater ID="uxRespList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="uxRespList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="uxRespList_ItemCommand">
                                                <ItemTemplate>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div id="uxRespostaText" visible="false" runat="server">
                                                                <input type="text" id="uxRespostaDissertativa" placeholder="Resposta" style="width:1000px" ></input>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div id="uxRespostaRadio" visible="false" runat="server">
                                                                <input type="radio" id="uxResposta" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Descricao")%>'/><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Descricao")%>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void uxQuestList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater rptRespostas = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("uxRespList"));

            QuestionarioPergunta pergunta = (QuestionarioPergunta)e.Item.DataItem;

            rptRespostas.DataSource = ctx.QuestionarioRespostas.Where(x => x.PergId == pergunta.Id).ToList();

            PergId.Text = pergunta.Id.ToString();

            rptRespostas.DataBind();

        }

    }

    protected void uxRespList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl uxRespostaText = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("uxRespostaText");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl uxRespostaRadio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("uxRespostaRadio");

            int PerguntaID = Int32.Parse(PergId.Text);
            var pergunta = ctx.QuestionarioPerguntas.Where(x => x.Id == PerguntaID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (pergunta.TipoPergunta == "Dissertativa")
            {
                uxRespostaText.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                uxRespostaRadio.Visible = true;
            }

        }

    }

    //Save here
    protected void uxSalvarPesquisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in uxRespList.Items)
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of your html input as below and based on your requirement you can modify the code.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in uxQuestList.Items)
{
    Repeater uxRespList = (Repeater)item.FindControl("uxRespList");

    foreach (RepeaterItem inneritem in uxRespList.Items)
    {
        HtmlInputText input = (HtmlInputText)inneritem.FindControl("uxRespostaDissertativa");
        if (input.Attributes["visible"] == "true")
        {
            var answer = input.Value;
        }

        HtmlInputRadioButton inputRadio = (HtmlInputRadioButton)inneritem.FindControl("uxRespostaRadio");
        if (inputRadio.Attributes["visible"] == "true")
        {
            var answer = inputRadio.Value;
        }
    }
}
```